# How to build TensorFlow Lite C API static library?

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, tensorflow-lite

I'd like to build the TensorFlow Lite as C API ***static library*** (Linux Debian x64). The [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#build_tensorflow_lite_c_library) state the following CMake workflow:

```
// get the sources
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src
// create a build directory
mkdir tflite_build
cd tflite_build
// build the lib using CMake
cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c
cmake --build . -j
```

However, this builds the ***shared library*** `libtensorflowlite_c.so`.

What would be the recommended way to build static version of the C API lib? Does modifying the CMake config files require expert CMake knowledge or it could be achieved rather easy?

Comment: Rather easy one. Add `-DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` to your CMake configuration step (`cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c`). Clear your build directory and rerun CMake commands.

Comment: @vre Could you be more specific: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Added an answer with explicit commands.

Answer (score 1):

According to the TensorFlow Lite [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/CMakeLists.txt#L19) file this should be rather easy. Add `-DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` to your CMake configuration step. That means, clear your build directory before doing any changes and rerun the CMake commands

```
cmake -S ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c -DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
cmake --build . -j
```

Be sure to also add to your project a dependency to TF-lite and its dependencies (as mentioned here in its [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L140)) if they are not header only, as TF-lite does not provide a CMake config package (AFAIK) that otherwise would include these transitive dependencies.

Comment: Works, `libtensorflowlite_c.a` is generated. What remains to be confirmed is that all symbols needed are actually linked inside the lib. Let me do a test app.

Comment: A static library is just a bunch of objects packed together. Nothing more. The linker is not involved when creating a static library.

Comment: Well, I thought so too, but look what [TensorFlow Lite C++ API document](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#step_5_build_tensorflow_lite) says: "Note: This generates a static library `libtensorflow-lite.a` in the current directory but the library isn't self-contained since all the transitive dependencies are not included. To use the library properly, you need to...", etc.

Comment: In the tensorflow lite [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L140) dependencies are resolved. You need to add those library dependencies (if they are not header only) to your minimal project too as TF-lite does not provide a CMake config package AFAIK.