# Xcode linking tensorflow lite library to a MacOS swift/Objective-C App

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, shared-libraries, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently developing an app that utilizes TensorFlow Lite. Up until now, I have been using Xcode (Swift + Objective-C) for the iOS version and C++ with a Python library for the UI on macOS. However, I'm now attempting to migrate the macOS version to a Swift/Objective-C app as well.

I'm encountering an issue with linking the TensorFlow Lite library. I must mention that I am not an expert in compilation, particularly with Xcode, and I consider myself a complete beginner in this field.

I attempted to build a static library based on the instructions provided in this Stack Overflow post:
[How to build TensorFlow Lite C API static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525641/how-to-build-tensorflow-lite-c-api-static-library)

Unfortunately, I encountered an issue outlined in another Stack Overflow question:
[TensorFlow static C API library - how to link with 10 sub-dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556391/tensorflow-static-c-api-library-how-to-link-with-10-sub-dependencies/72100557#72100557)

Considering this, I thought maybe I should try linking the shared library directly, similar to what I did for the C++ version, rather than dealing with multiple dependencies.

I attempted the approach described in this Stack Overflow post:
[Xcode linking against static and dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699389/xcode-linking-against-static-and-dynamic-library)

But since I'm trying to link a .so and not a .dylib I'm blocked at the second step (embedding the file, the file is not appearing in finder)

Edit: I've build tensorflow as a dylib and managed to pass step 2 but the error message below remains the same (except .so is .dylib now)

So I'm stuck at this error message:

```
dyld[31578]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflowlite.so
  Referenced from: <B747542F-7B2F-37D7-82A9-1BDB1E9C13D0> /Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Reason: tried: '/Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '../tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '../tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '../tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/Users/val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fssgyguqotwbodfhfxrzdhmwlqao/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '../tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtensorflowlite.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

To investigate further, I ran the command `otool -L libtensorflowlite.so` to check for any dependencies. Here is the output from otool:

```
../tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/libtensorflowlite.so:
    @rpath/libtensorflowlite.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1500.65.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1971.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Based on the output, it seems that the problem probably comes from the self-reference made by libtensorflowlite.so.

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this problem or if I'm heading in the right direction, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those who would find this post. I finally succeeded by compiling tensorflow lite static library and by linking all the dependencies (static lib) one by one in my Xcode project.
I just followed the post I linked in my question: [TensorFlow static C API library - how to link with 10 sub-dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556391/tensorflow-static-c-api-library-how-to-link-with-10-sub-dependencies/72100557#72100557)

In my opinion it's not the "best" way to do it, but it works.