# How to build Tensorflow Lite C API?

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, build, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to build using cmake to use the tensorflow Lite c API.
However, when the build completes, libtensorflowlite_c.so is not generated.
I would like to know more about the Tensorflow Lite c API.

I ran the build with these url's but could not do it.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake
[How to build TensorFlow Lite C API static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525641/how-to-build-tensorflow-lite-c-api-static-library)

Comment: You need to clarify the "could not do it" part, details are missing and are very important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.